# Chrome doesn't load gwt source maps

Tags: java, gwt, source-maps, gwt-dev-mode

Recently chrome stopped to show Source Maps.

I had a some break with my project and now with the new version of gwt and chrome I don't see java sources in source tab.

I'm using super dev mode. 
Compiled file (*.cache.js) that I receive from Code Server contains header for Source Maps:

```
X-SourceMap:/sourcemaps/Simulation/gwtSourceMap.json
```

Code Server doesn't print that it has sent Source Maps (as it was before), only that Compilation was successful

I have: 
gwt version 2.5.0
Chrome verson 25.0.1364.172
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (but the problem is reproduced in Windows and MacOS as well)

Comment: Yes, I suggest you upgrade as well and tell us if the problem still exist !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you hit https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7725

Try to update to 2.5.1.

Comment: great, thanks a lot! But now I cannot run anything from Intellij IDEA, like Tomcat or Code Server. (com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclaredType; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1052417216019896795, local class serialVersionUID = -8155793964565947646)...

Comment: @Isaak make sure to delete the `gwt-unitCache` directories, along with any other temporary files GWT generates.

Comment: @Colin thanks! It worked for super dev mode but didn't for local tomcat. But probably I should clean some more places...

Comment: Hi! I have similar/same problem with 2.6.1.
I use Super Dev Mode in Idea 14. Compilation goes successfull and SDM server starts with messages "Source Maps Enabled".But it seems that SDM server doesn`t give access to sourcemaps or even it doesn`t create them at all. After module is started, there are logs with 500 error on
GET:http://127.0.0.1:9876/sourcemaps/MyModule/gwtSourceMap.json
I would appreciate any help on my problem. Thanks in advance.